# Could not resolve io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.4.3

Tags: android, gradle, koin

I'm having issues in a small project. I get this error message when I try to import the latest koin version 3.4.3 to my Android project:

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.insert-koin:koin-core:3.4.3.
```

Then I am building (after I have sync).

The dependencies and versions I am handling are:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
ext.koinVersion = '3.4.3'
ext.appcompatVersion = '1.3.1'
ext.materialVersion = '1.4.0'
ext.constraintlayoutVersion = '2.0.4'
ext.coreKtxVersion = '1.6.0'
ext.multiDexVersion = '2.0.1'
ext.targetSdkVersion = 31
ext.compileSdkVersion = 31
ext.buildToolsVersion = '31.0.0'
ext.retrofitVersion = '2.9.0'
ext.okHttpInterceptorVersion = '4.10.0'
ext.recyclerviewVersion = '1.2.1'
ext.junitVersion = '4.13.1'
ext.junitAndroidxExtVersion = '1.1.3'
ext.junitAndroidxCoreVersion = '1.4.0'
ext.junitAndroidxExtKtxVersion = '1.1.3'
ext.testRunnerVersion = '1.4.0'
ext.testCoreKtxVersion = '1.4.0'
```

build.gradle (project):

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10"
        classpath "io.insert-koin:koin-gradle-plugin:$koinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and finally, build.gradle (app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }

    signingConfigs {

        release {
            storeFile file("keystore.debug")
        }
    }


    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "com.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/*.kotlin_module']
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    androidTestImplementation "junit:junit:$junitVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$junitAndroidxExtVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$junitAndroidxCoreVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:$junitAndroidxExtKtxVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$testRunnerVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core-ktx:$testCoreKtxVersion"


    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$coreKtxVersion"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraintlayoutVersion"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$appcompatVersion"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multiDexVersion"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerviewVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$materialVersion"
    implementation "io.insert-koin:koin-android:$koinVersion"
    api "io.insert-koin:koin-core:$koinVersion"

    //Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofitVersion"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpInterceptorVersion"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe you just need to add `mavenCentral()` to your  `allprojects.repositories` config : the `koin-core` is indeed available in mavenCentral repo only,  not in `google()` repo